# Float div inside spans

Tags: html, css

I have this code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1xvw91a/1/)

I would like to know if its possible to make `div` float inside text, like its following text?

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Pause and play icons will automatically be attached to every mp3 song in text. Like this for example: </span>
<div class="a"></div><span> ut laoreet hendrerit mi. Nam vestibulum viverra diam. Nullam eros ipsum, rutrum ut, ultricies sed, congue sed, est. Pellentesque porttitor. Donec dictum urna eu mi. Maecenas in lorem.</span>
```

Comment: [`display:inline-block`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/o1xvw91a/3/) is your friend.

Comment: in your code, div should be a span. Your span parent could be a p, div , ...

Comment: A `div` should **never** be inside a `span`, it's an abomination of semantics

Comment: (deleted a comment of mine, I was under the false impression that an `a`-tag was involved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `display:inline-block` along with `vertical-align`, as you can set it to fit you better.

---

To users on comments:

This is valid HTML, because `span` is **sibling** of `div` and **not** its  parent.

---

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Pause and play icons will automatically be attached to every mp3 song in text. Like this for example: </span>
<div class="a"></div><span> ut laoreet hendrerit mi. Nam vestibulum viverra diam. Nullam eros ipsum, rutrum ut, ultricies sed, congue sed, est. Pellentesque porttitor. Donec dictum urna eu mi. Maecenas in lorem.</span>
```

Comment: Why am I not getting the same results on fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/o1xvw91a/4/ (div is full left and the text right).  I would like it to be like the part of the text itself, so it behaves exactly like some text word, flowing with words on the same line. Sorry if I cant explain better.

Comment: @Toniq now I understood you, take a look at updated answer

Comment: Whilst this is a smashing answer - to the OP, I would STRONGLY suggest against having a div class of "a"  that is then referenced as .a in the CSS. Way too easy to get lost in actual "a" elements. and end up targetting something unintended. Not a fault of this answer, but rather the OP's question, but I thought it would be worthwhile here since this answer was accepted. But apart from that - great answer

Comment: @gavgrif thanks, I'm with you too, but I'm guessing OP did this just for demo. :)

Comment: Obviously the OP's problem, but I'd start with changing the HTML to be valid before applying CSS.  [a span should never be a parent to a div].

Comment: have you look at the markup? they are siblings.. which is valid